# Swift: Instance variable takes precedence over class constructor?

Tags: swift, core-image

I'm having an issue while attempting to extend UIImage. I'm creating a new method that as part of some processing creates a CIImage. Unfortunately since UIImage contains an instance variable with the name CIImage, the compiler seems to think that my constructor is trying to reference that instance variable rather than the CIImage class:

```
extension UIImage {    
  func newMethod() {
    let image = CIImage(CGImage: self.CGImage) // Error: Cannot invoke 'CIImage' with an argument list of type '(CGImage: CGImage!)'
  }
}
```

Is there a workaround for this to call the CIImage constructor from within the context of a UIImage extension?

Answer (score 4):

You can reference the type explicitly by prefacing it with the module name.

```
extension UIImage {    
  func newMethod() {
    let image = CoreImage.CIImage(CGImage: self.CGImage)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can work around this by creating a function outside the extension and then calling this method within the extension:

```
func CIImageFromCGImage(image: CGImage) -> CIImage {
  return CIImage(CGImage: image)
}
```

Pretty silly though. Is there a better way?

Comment: I have already notice that and I had to do exactly the same think you did